# How do I get Dynamodb Item count from item summary NOT scan

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to return the item count from my dynamodb table. I already have a getLiveItemCount() function which looks something like this:

```golang
func GetLiveItemCount(tableName string) *int64 {
    dynamodbClient := createDynamoDBClient()

    items, _ := dynamodbClient.Scan(&dynamodb.ScanInput{
        TableName: aws.String(tableName),
    })

    return items.Count
}
```

However, I'm looking to have another function that returns the item count from the most recently updated item metrics that [item summary](https://bobbyhadz.com/images/blog/aws-dynamodb-count-items/items-summary-section.webp) uses (items summary includes `item count`, `table size`, and `Average item size` which are updated every 6 hours). Is there any way to get this value in Golang?

Comment: describeTable should return this data

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/#DynamoDB.DescribeTable it returns https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/#TableDescription

Comment: @IłyaBursov This is exactly what I was looking for. Did you want to formulate this into an answer so that I could give you credit for the answer or would you like me to make one (I will still credit you but you won't receive the points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get those values you call DescribeTable:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html